# AX 2012 legacy report (ReportRun) called from an AIF web service

Tags: report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, aif, morph-x

Is it possible to call a legacy AX report (not SSRS) from within a AIF web service hosted in AX?

We have a legacy report (not SSRS) that we want to call via a web service to generate a PDF on the fly in a folder and return a file name.

Calling the web service returns a message (fault) that the ReportRun object can not be instantiated.

Comment: Which message exactly?

Comment: Please include code of what you've tried.